# multiple updates in one submit in SPA page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a web page written in ASP.net where it finds a list of employees, displays them in a listview and allow the user to change different statuses for each employee.

On each row I have employee information like name, date of birth, address and then 4 status fields that are displayed as checkboxes and a comment field where the user can type a comment explaining why they changed a certain status.

Currently in Listview, there is an edit, delete button when they click edit, the checkboxes and text field are displayed the user updates them and click save.

asp.net will do a postback to save the changes for this row and then fetches the data again to refresh the list.

The problem I am having is the list is very large (more than 3000 names), so I am using pagination to show 50 to 100 names on each page. This is still a big performance problem because after every line update a query needs to run to fetch those names again, and with ASP.NET the server is generating the html and passing everything to the browser.

The customer wants the page to be mobile friendly too, so I am thinking to redo the page using Angular on front end with web-api or mvc.net on back end that returns JSON.

My question is there an easy way to do this and allow the user to change the status for multiple employees on the same page at once and then click one submit to update all the changes? if I do it this way, there will be less queries to run and it will be faster for the user because they don't have to wait after every line update.

Any examples will be greatly appreciated, unless there is a different way to implement this, in this case please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to fetch all the data again. The client knows the data you sent to the server, so the server just needs to send back a value indicating it was successfully changed (or not) and then the client can update the DOM.

Comment: Other users might have changed some data too during that time, or added/deleted names so I will have to refresh it.

Comment: Why couldn't you just update the row that has been changed?

Comment: Then consider using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to get real time updates

Answer (score 0):

I have a thought that may work.
On load render names and use pagination.
Then use ajax to send the post to server and change data in database.
When editing has returned successful then only change the values that have been edited using javascript for the user to view.

Comment: Other users might have changed the data or added/deleted names. So I have to do a refresh anyway, but I prefer to do it once after a page update and notify them of any conflicts. I just feel it's an over kill to do it after each line update.

Comment: You can have it like a data grid or like excel and when done editing have a save button on the bottom to save their changes. If they made a change and did not save let them know if they try to leave the page. How ever I don't think this is ever going to work because if I change 2 rows someone may have changed the 3rd and then I decide the edit them.